# update currently message by inline keyboard Telegram VB.NET

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

hello i try to updating Message by inline keyboard.

telegram OnMessageReceived function:

```
 Dim ID As String = e.Message.From.Id.ToString ' it is your id
 Select Case e.Message.Text
 Case "/ts"
 Await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(ID, "Hello", replyMarkup:=CreateInLineMainMenuMarkup)
Return
End Select
```

Inline Keyboard function's

```
 Public Shared Function CreateInLineMainMenuMarkup() As IReplyMarkup

    Dim buttonsList As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
    buttonsList.Add("Refresh", "test")

    Return CreateInlineKeyboardButton(buttonsList, 1)

End Function

Public Shared Function CreateInlineKeyboardButton(ByVal buttonList As Dictionary(Of String, String), ByVal columns As Integer) As IReplyMarkup
    Dim rows As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling(CDbl(buttonList.Count) / CDbl(columns)))
    Dim buttons As InlineKeyboardButton()() = New InlineKeyboardButton(rows - 1)() {}

    For i As Integer = 0 To buttons.Length - 1
        buttons(i) = buttonList.Skip(i * columns).Take(columns).[Select](Function(direction) TryCast(New InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(direction.Key, direction.Value), InlineKeyboardCallbackButton)).ToArray()
    Next

    Return New InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons)
End Function
```

[Image To explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhj0c.png)

Question here,can i update text message from "Hello", To be "Done". using inline keyboard click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need handle OnCallbackQuery event.

first :

```
AddHandler bot.OnCallbackQuery, AddressOf OnCallbackQuery
```

then add function OnCallbackQuery (that to handle any action of callback inline keyboard)

```
Private Async Sub OnCallbackQuery(sender As Object, e As CallbackQueryEventArgs)
    Dim call_data As String = e.CallbackQuery().Message.Text
    Dim message_id As Long = e.CallbackQuery().Message.MessageId
    Dim chat_id As Long = e.CallbackQuery().Message.Chat.Id
    Dim callback As Long = e.CallbackQuery.Id

    If call_data.Equals("Hello") Then
    Dim answer As String = "Done"
    Dim r As Telegram.Bot.Types.Message = Await bot.EditMessageTextAsync(chat_id, message_id, (answer))
    Dim r2 As Boolean = Await bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(callbackQueryId:=callback, text:=answer)

    End If
End Sub
```

Notice that, it gonna update inline keyboard message to normal text message.

Hope it help.

Comment: Can i ask how can i make that inline static inline keyboard, because it changed to normal text after update. ?!

Comment: fell free to make new question, and well help, as well.